# Oauth 2 spring boot client custom configuration

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

the authentication server uses traditional terms like api_key instead of client id and api_secret in place of client_secret and the callback will contain parameters as follows callbackurl/request_token="clksdnfvklcm" instead of code="nvckjlefdkm"$state="somestate" and no state parameter i have no idea how to implement it correctly
the way i tried has so many flaws that i created a login page where i provided a link for oauth server uri like oauthserver/api_key=mcklfdms and then i created a filter before oauth filter and redirecting it with correct format so that the request would convert to oauth/code=cnjdsn instead of oauth/callback/request_token=cnjdsn 
can anyone provide me the correct way to implement it

### Request Resolver

```
@Component
public class KiteAuthorizationRequestResolver implements OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver {
    DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver defaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver;
    ClientRegistration clientRegistration;
    public KiteAuthorizationRequestResolver(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,String authorizationBaseUri){
        this.defaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver=new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(
                clientRegistrationRepository,authorizationBaseUri);
        this.clientRegistration=clientRegistrationRepository.findByRegistrationId("kite");
    }
    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest resolve(HttpServletRequest request) {
        OAuth2AuthorizationRequest oAuth2AuthorizationRequest=defaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.resolve(request);
        if(request!=null){
            return requestResolver(oAuth2AuthorizationRequest);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest resolve(HttpServletRequest request, String clientRegistrationId) {
        OAuth2AuthorizationRequest oAuth2AuthorizationRequest=defaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.resolve(request,clientRegistrationId);
        if(request!=null){
            return requestResolver(oAuth2AuthorizationRequest);
        }
        return null;
    }
    private OAuth2AuthorizationRequest requestResolver(OAuth2AuthorizationRequest request){
        Map<String,Object> parms=new HashMap<>();
        if(request.getAdditionalParameters()!=null){
            parms.putAll(request.getAdditionalParameters());
        }
        parms.put("api_key",this.clientRegistration.getClientId());
        OAuth2AuthorizationRequest oAuth2AuthorizationRequest=OAuth2AuthorizationRequest
                .from(request)
                .state("hello")
                .additionalParameters(parms)
                .build();
        return oAuth2AuthorizationRequest;
    }
}
```

### Filter

```
package com.kumar.coingen.filter;

import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/oauth/code/kite")
@Order(-150)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(!request.getParameter("code").isEmpty()){
            chain.doFilter(request,response);
        }
        String code=request.getParameter("request_token");
        HttpServletRequest servletRequest=(HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse servletResponse=(HttpServletResponse)response;
        servletResponse.sendRedirect(request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+"/"+((HttpServletRequest) request).getServletPath()+"/code="+code+"&state=hello");
    }
}
```

**please let me know if it can be done without using the filter to redirect **

Comment: please provide me any implementations if present

Comment: please let me know if it can be done without using the filter to redirect